# Rails: Cucumber with Guard (+spork and +rspec) not running features upon changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, guard, spork

I have recently tried installing Cucumber to supplement my testing environment. I already had Guard working with Spork and Rspec perfectly. I have set everything up so that it runs now, with Cucumber included, but two things are acting a bit funky.

**First issue:** when Guard runs the Cucumber tests, it pauses for about 10 seconds after printing "Disabling profiles..." After about 10 seconds, it runs the tests perfectly. 
**Second Issue:** when I make changes to my features (which are stored in subdirectories, such as /features/users/sign_in.feature) or step definitions, guard doesn't run the tests. In order for me to run the tests, I have to manually hit  and Guard proceeds to run all tests again. Clearly, that defeats the purpose of guard.

Here is some of my code:

**Guard Terminal Output**

```
ben@ben-K53SV:~/rails_projects/katmeer4$ bundle exec guard
16:51:57 - INFO - Guard is using Libnotify to send notifications.
16:51:57 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
16:51:57 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
16:51:57 - INFO - Running all specs
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
.....[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
........F....

Failures:

  1) User abilities admin Index Page 
     Failure/Error: it {should have_selector('div', text: 'delete')}
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "div" with text "delete" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/role_spec.rb:38:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.18 seconds
18 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/role_spec.rb:38 # User abilities admin Index Page 


Randomized with seed 16984

16:52:08 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec, Cucumber
Using RSpec, Rails
Using Cucumber, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8990!
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
16:52:18 - INFO - Spork server for RSpec, Cucumber successfully started

16:52:18 - INFO - Running all features
Disabling profiles...
..
P-

(::) pending steps (::)

features/users/sign_in.feature:9:in `Then I see an invalid login message'

1 scenario (1 pending)
4 steps (1 skipped, 1 pending, 2 passed)
0m0.827s
```

**Important Guardfile Code**

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' },
               :rspec_env    => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end


guard 'cucumber' do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end
```

**features/support/env.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
end

Spork.each_run do
end

require 'cucumber/rails'

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false
begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to split the env.rb code into the prefork and each_run blocks.  Try:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  require 'cucumber/rails'
end

Spork.each_run do
  ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

  begin
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  rescue NameError
    raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish   to use it."
  end

  Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
end
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I made the changes above, but unfortunately Guard still doesn't pick up on changes I make to files (in regards to cucumber).